# Excel Fill alphanumeric values

Tags: excel, fill

I would like to fill A000001, A000002, till A100000. 
Now do it by dragging the fill handle.

I also tried to fill using Step Value and Stop Value. It works for 1,2,3 to 100000. But it does not work for alphanumeric filling like A000001, A000002 etc

Comment: You could try and have one column with `A` and another with the number from `000001...100000` and then `CONCATENATE` the two.

Comment: I have a roundabout way of doing this, but better than dragging for lacks of rows. Want that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the step value method to generate 1 to 100000 in column A (from cell A1). And paste the below formula in cell B1,

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=1,"A00000"&A1,IF(LEN(A1)=2,"A0000"&A1,IF(LEN(A1)=3,"A000"&A1,IF(LEN(A1)=4,"A00"&A1,IF(LEN(A1)=5,"A0"&A1,IF(LEN(A1)=6,"A"&A1))))))
```

Just double click the fill handle in B1 to generate for the entire range. This is a simpler way of doing this. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The standard method is Create custom list but since you are looking for a long one so practically impossible,, another is Flash Fill,, and older one is write A000001 in cell A000002 in below cell select both drag it till you need.

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late, however I can provide a tip it may be helpful to someone looking for same issue.

if you want fill the alpha numeric series by dragging the fill handle, just need to add a simple formula in the first row:

```
="A"&TEXT(ROWS($1:1),"000000")
```

In the above formula: the text “A” is constant, you can change them to your needed text, and the number “000000” is the variable which will be increased by dragging the fill handle.

Also if you want to add a string at end , you just need to change the formula to this,

```
 ="A"&TEXT(ROWS($1:1),"000000")&"-VAL"
```

Then it will give you something like this,

> A000001-VAL, A000002-VAL, A000003-VAL.....

You can also change the starting number too.

Regards